# Sharing single jwt token between multiple project to authenticate

Tags: laravel-7

I have two API projects. The main project is a Lumen project and JWT authentication is written there. The other project is a Laravel project which has APIs. Both the projects have tymon/jwt-auth installed and set up. And both the projects use the same secret key generated by JWT in the .env file.

My requirement is to validate the token from both sides (between these two project).

But it gave me "message": "Unauthenticated." message. Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://laravelquestions.com/2021/07/01/how-to-build-jwt-authentication-between-multiple-projects-in-laravel/

```
this is the very first time am working with JWT tokens and I have two API projects. Our main project is a Laravel project and JWT authentication is written there. The other project is a Lumen project which has some service APIs. Both the projects have tymon/jwt-auth installed and set up. And both the projects use the same secret key generated by JWT in the .env file.

My requirement is to validate the token received by the main Laravel project which has the authentication in the Lumen service project. Both the projects use different databases and the Lumen project does not have the users table.

So far what I’ve done in the Lumen project is created and registered a middleware in order to validate the received token and protected the routes using the created middleware. And the routes hit the middleware.

Then I installed the tymon/jwt as below:

composer require tymon/jwt-auth

Added the created middleware inside bootstrap/app.php as below:

$app->routeMiddleware([
‘auth’ => AppHttpMiddlewareAuthMiddleware::class
]);

Uncommented below the line in boostrap/app.php under providers section

$app->register(AppProvidersAuthServiceProvider::class);

Added below line to the providers in bootstrap/app.php

$app->register(TymonJWTAuthProvidersLumenServiceProvider::class);

pasted the generated JWT JWT_SECRET by main Laravel Project inside the .env file of Lumen project

Now for testing purposes, I wanted to create a token using the JWT_SECRET and validate the token using the same key in the Lumen project.
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29900066)